# EF6.1 Upgrade Issues: To SQL Server CE file Location and [NotMapped] Properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I really appreciate any insight anyone can provide.

I've come back to a project that was using the EF6.0 rc preview. After updating the projects EF to 6.1 and updating the SQL Server CE I have two problems.

**[UPDATE]**
Problems 1 & 2 solved **Problem 3 is not**.

**PROBLEM 3 -**
Now with the path set via a connection string as explained above, migrations called via the package manager are not working as its an invalid path.  Any ideas anyone?

When I start up the debug process, I get problem 1 and the exceptions crash; but it does create a `.sdf` file although in the wrong location as explained in problem 2.

**1. NOT MAPPED PROPERTY AND UNSUPPORTED BY LINQ ERROR**

During the initial creation process I get an exception

```
List<Equipment> duplicateTags = db.EquipmentReg
                .GroupBy(e => e.TagAndLocation)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .SelectMany(g => g).ToList<Equipment>();
```

The exception is related to the `TagAndLocation`. `TagAndLocation` is defined in the model by

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates concatenation object that will not be mapped in the database but will be in the
/// Object Relational Mapping (ORM) of the EF model.
/// </summary>
[NotMapped]
public string TagAndLocation { get { return Tag + " (" + Location.Name + ")"; } }
```

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   Additional information: The specified type member 'TagAndLocation' is
>   not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members,
>   and entity navigation properties are supported.

Why is this happening now?

**2. CONNECTION STRING NOT APPLYING LOCATION**

My connection isn't applying the path properly anymore.

I have it being done by a `DbConfiguration` class which auto runs, I guess due to its inherited class type. As shown below

```
class HAIDbJob_EFConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public HAIDbJob_EFConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);

        // Create the connection string programmatically - Setting the filename and path.
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory(
                "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0",
                System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Databases"),
                @"Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Databases") +
                @"\Hazardous_Area_Database_Job.sdf"));
    }
}
```

Instead of creating a file in the runtime location `...\bin\Debug\Databases\Hazardous_Area_Database_Job.sdf`, it creates it at 
`..\bin\Debug\HA_Inspector.HAI_Database.HAI_Job_EF_Model.Hazardous_Area_Database_Job.sdf`

Which is the full namespace of the database model... I have tried a few solutions found for other people problems of a slightly different nature, but none of it works. Any ideas would be extremely appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

1: The EF provider attempt to translate TagAndLocation to SQL and fails. You must use LINQ to Objects for this grouping.

2: Why not have a named connectionstring in your app.config, or pass it in the DbContext constructor.

Comment: Is there any way you can programmatically change the database name and filepath at runtime?

Comment: Sure - http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html (last sections)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**
I did a string compare in the group by statement since location has a string member Location.Name.

**SOLUTION 2**
When I originally wrote this I wanted to dynamically name the database all the time and this is why I wrote the initialiser class. 
To get around the problem, I just followed Erik's advice and put a XAML connection string in app.config using "Source=./Databases"..... to get the subfolder.

Comment: **PROBLEM 3 - **
Now with the path set via a connection string as explained above, migrations called via the package manager are not working as its an invalid path.  Any ideas anyone?